# Watson Assistant detecting wrong entity

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I am developing a skill that includes a branch for making a health service appointment. After recognising the intent, it lands on a node that attempts to fill slots for entities @service_type, @practitioner_type, and @appointment_type. However, when I trigger it with a request for a "medical appointment", it assigns the value "medical" to an entity called @associate_type (which is used in an entirely different intent) and leaves the slot for @service_type empty.

The crazy thing is that the training examples for @associate_type do not even include the word "medical", whereas those for @service_type include it 3 times. The only connection I can see between the two is that @associate_type contains a value called "doctor" (with synonyms that include "physician").

Is it possible that my entity definitions are interacting with Watson's underlying conversation model to create this ambiguity?

Comment: P.S. I also cannot remember the last time I saw the "Watson is training" message in the "Try it pane". Is it possible that re-training is not triggering?

Comment: Can you reduce to a sample that can reproduce the issue and can be shared?

Comment: I'll try, but I suspect it would require a massive chunk of the skill in order to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just the reduced entities that reproduce the issue should be fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @SimonO'Doherty. I fixed this issue by deleting annotations from the entity that was stealing the slot, but I'm getting many similar issues. I believe I'm trying to cover too many features (sub-skills) within one skill, so I'm getting clashes between entities. I'm going to try to rationalise the entities and use logic to work out the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Remove annotations (from other entities / intents) that clash with the target entity.